# Copy files in java eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, path, relative-path

I put a file in a folder named "templates" placed in the `src/` of my eclipse project. I'm trying to make a copy of that file, and want to edit it. Here's my code:

```
InputStream source = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("templates/file.docx");
File dest = new File("templates/updatedfile.docx");

try{
    Files.copy(source, dest.toPath());
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I'm getting a java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: template/updatedfile.docx! What have I done wrong?

Edit: Sorry, fixed a typo in the code, exact exception is now updated

Comment: Seems that this file *templates/file.docx* is not being recognized as a resource in your application. Make sure this file is inside your sources. Otherwise, I would recommend using the concrete path instead.

Comment: @BackSlash that's a generic Q/A for `NullPointerException`. This case is a rather specific problem, IMO the API should throw an `IOException` for not finding the file at `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Where exactly do you get the exception?

Comment: @jny after I made the changes as suggested in the answer, the exception is back to nullpointerexception!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

to see where is the root folder java looks at by default, which is probably your "Project folder". the `/src` folder is under the project folder so you probably have to add that to the path too:

`"src/templates/updatedfile.docx"`

Comment: user.dir returned /Users/username/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/ and after doing the suggested changes, it's back to nullpointerexception.

Comment: and your `src` folder is under what `user.dir` returned?

Comment: Nope, it's in my documents folder!!

Comment: Exactly. When you put a path like `/templates/updatedfile.docx` or `src/templates/updatedfile.docx` java is assuming it exists under the folder returned by `user.dir`. If it doesn't, either move the file or put the absolute path like `C:\Documents\..\...\..` etc

Comment: I understand, but I want this app to be portable. What can I do?

Comment: You can move the file i guess?

Comment: then it will be moved in my eclipse app, and I want the project app to be portable - any ideas?

Comment: put it where your `.class` files are?

Comment: are you sure, and where are they located?

Comment: `YourProjectFolder/bin/` . Note that there may be more subfolders under the `bin` folder, one for each `package` in your project

Comment: and what would be my input and output paths? thanks very much for the help so far

Comment: if you put it in the `bin` folder then i guess "bin\file_name`. If its in any subfolder then `bin\subfolder\file_name` etc. Or just put it in the folder returned by `user.dir`

Comment: there's no bin folder in my project, but there's a build folder - shall i put it there?

Comment: You can put it anywhere i guess but if you want to find w/o the absolute path it has to be under the folder `user.dir`

Answer (score 0):

When you run an application in eclipse it runs in your project folder. So when you create a new file `templates/updatedfile.docx`, you are trying to create a new directory and file at the same time.
Try creatign `templates` directory in your project folder and run the app again.
Alternatively in your code you can check if the directory exists, and create it if it does not.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I already have the templates/ directory - just need to copy the file there!

Comment: Well, it should not be in your `src` directory. Just create templates directory in the project root directory and put your source file there. You would need to change the code for the source file path.

Comment: But if you want to keep things the way they are now, you need to change the path for dest file to `bin/templates/...`. That is where your app is reading the source file from.

Comment: I've tried keeping everything in the root folder to use relative path for input (templates/file.docx) and output(templates/updatedfile.docx) but it didn't work!

Comment: I'm getting a java.nio.file.nosuchfileexception template/file.docx

Comment: The exception you posted say `template`, not `templates`.... Is it typo in the code or comment?